# Flutter app Bar leaving space at the top of the emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-android

I have a normal scaffold having a `appBar:` & `body:`

**CODE**

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**Expected Output**
[image]

I want to move this appBar to the top of the mobile screen. Why it is leaving the space at the top

NOTE: I AM RUNNING MY FLUTTER APP ON AVD EMULATOR

Comment: With some recent update in the framework they have initiated safe area by default. This is what's cause the space between the top of the screen and your app bar. This is to prevent the app bar to over flow the not responding section or the notification tray.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Pixel 5 version. 
You can test in other AVD. I use Pixel 3a XL.

Should work well!